# Django use model EmailField raising AttributeError

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I've added a model boolean field called 'is_dotcom' to my admin list_display, and the implementation is:

```
email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)

def is_dotcom(self):
    return self.email.lower().endsWith(".com")

is_dotcom.admin_order_field = 'email'
is_dotcom.boolean = True
is_dotcom.short_description = 'Company?'
```

But all this yields on my admin page is "(None)".  I'm expecting True/False (though *sometimes* my booleans show as a green check or red no entry sign, anyone know why that is?)

I've based this code on an example in the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/).

I'm assuming that "(None)" is being shown because the is_dotcom() method is raising an AttributeError which django is catching.  I'm guessing that it's legal to call .lower() on an EmailField but I don't know for sure (what do you guys do for reference documentation?)  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

```
    return self.email.lower().endsWith(".com")
```

The method is [`.endswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).
Please note the absence of camel-case.

A simplified example which reproduces the error:

```
>>> 'foo'.endsWith('test')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'endsWith'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Curse these new-fangled non-compiled languages ;-)

Comment: Also realized why it was showing True/False instead of green check/red no-entry sign for one of my boolean columns - I had not set field.boolean = True for that column.  Need more coffee!